# How to make openssl s_client using default CA

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, openssl

is there a way to configure openssl so that it would use some default CA file (ex./etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt)  when running s_client command with no -CAfile option specified?

Comment: Do `man ca` and search for `configuration file`.

Comment: Could you pls clarify what parameter needs to be changed? I've tried openssl.cnf but it doesn't work.

Comment: That is a much more specific question, and to my mind, a better one.  Try showing us what you've done so far, and showing how it didn't work, and you'll probably get better answers than if you ask to be spoonfed from the beginning.

Comment: Well, first of all, I've been reading the man and the openssl web site and there is no any word about possibility to configure -CAfile in the .cnf. So, I've tired: dir = /usr/lib/ssl and certificate = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt . None of this works (as expected actually). So, may be you have some better idea?

Comment: Please, **edit this into your question**.  **Show** us bits of your config file, and how you invoke `openssl`, and why you think it doesn't work.  You might also want to read [our guide on asking good questions](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think the question is alright. I'm not asking 'how to configure in .cnf...'. I'm asking if this is possible at all. So, there is no point to discuss the conf file etc if the answer is NO. Only if the answer is Yes, then you could point to man or whatever.

Comment: As I read it, it ought to be possible.  I know for a fact that `openssl s_client` on my system reads `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf`, because I saw it open and read the file with `strace`.  The `man` page I pointed you to above documents the format for specifying a CA in the conf file.

Comment: Ok, I've been reading other resources and it seems like this is a) system dependant b) openssl version dependant. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: OK, I'm a RedHat/Fedora man myself, so can't help with that.  I've tagged the question accordingly; hopefully someone Ubuntuey will be able to shed more light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuration file is not the answer. It is organized into sections using lines with square brackets like `[default_CA]` and `[req_exts]`. There are a few sections that all `openssl` subcommands read (for engines and addOIDs) but beyond that only the sections that apply to a particular subcommand and sometimes mode of that subcommand are used, and no such sections apply to `s_client`.

The library provides a routine `SSL_CTX_default_verify_paths` for applications to call (and I believe many/most other apps do) and the location(s) used there are indeed system (or packager) dependent EDIT: or can also be set by environment variables. But s_client.c only calls this routine If you *do* specify at least one valid -CA{file,path} argument not if you don't, which seems unhelpful. There's a ticket on this from 2010 with no action shown.

Comment: Thanks, Dave; that's pretty definitive.  Would you have a link to the open ticket that you could edit into your question, so anyone in the future can see if the situation has improved?  Spoonboy, sorry I was no help.

Comment: Thanks Dave for clarifying this. I came to the same conclusion. As well, I've checked on OL6 (which should be similar to RHEL) and it works the same way there, i.e. you must specify either CAfile or CApath in order to make openssl s_client command use CA certificates file. If the CA file or path is not specified in the command it will fail to find the default certificates path.

Comment: @MadHatter The URL is http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2387 but you have to login first -- guest/guest allows readonly access.

Comment: Thanks - curious minds yet to come will thank you for that.

Comment: According to that ticket, a fix has been merged: Fixed in branch, to be released post-1.0.2

commit 3938694b2a770efad980c947b68981b110e784d6
Author: Rich Salz <rsalz@akamai.com>
Date:   Fri Aug 15 14:27:04 2014 -0400